# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column cannot be null?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

when i post data in field, i have java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'name' cannot be null. ?
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [Column 'name' cannot be null] [insert into user_message (email,message,mobile,name) values (?,?,?,?)]

*
My Entity*

```
Entity
@Table (name="UserMessage")
public class UserMessage {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column (name = "name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column (name = "mobile", length = 40, nullable = false)
    private String mobile;
    
    @Column (name ="email", length = 70, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    @Column (name="message", length = 1000, nullable = false)
    private String message;
    
    
    public UserMessage () {
    
    }

    public UserMessage(String message, String name, String mobile, String email) {
        this.message = message;
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.email = email;
    }`
```

- getters and setters

*Contorller *

```
`@Autowired
    private MessegeServiceWeb serv;
    public HomeController(MessegeServiceWeb serv) {
        this.serv = serv;
    }

@PostMapping ("/")
    public String saveCars(@ModelAttribute ("usermessage")UserMessage usermessage) {
        serv.saveMessage(usermessage);
        return "redirect:/";
    }`
```

*Service*

```
`@Service
@Transactional
public class MessegeServiceWeb implements MessageService {
    
    private MessageRepo messagerepo;
    public MessegeServiceWeb(MessageRepo messagerepo) {
        this.messagerepo = messagerepo;
    }


    @Override
    public UserMessage saveMessage(UserMessage usermessag) {
        return messagerepo.save(usermessag);
    }`
```

***And my template ***

```
<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${usermessage}" method ="post">
              <div>
                <input field="*{name}" type="text" placeholder="Ваше ім'я" required="required"/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input field="*{email}" type="email" placeholder="Ваша почта" required="required" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <input field="*{mobile}" name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Мобільний" required="required"/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input field="*{message}" type="text" class="message-box" placeholder="Повідомлення про проблему"  required="required"/>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex ">
                <button>
                  Send
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>


When try past data have next Exception
```